# How to store android mobile Application data store Cloud database (like my sql)?

Tags: android, cloud

How to store android mobile Application data store Cloud database (like my sql)?

i'm new for developing android apps. i want to how android mobile application data store and retrive the eucalyptus cloud database like mySQL.

Comment: did you asking about web services?

Comment: Your question need a little work, English may not be your first language and we dont care about mistake but we must be able to understand you so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

The cloud is a term for a group of servers offering a service. So if your hosting(storing) your data in the cloud it means you have signed up for a service that allows you to remotely store and retrieve your data.

The data will be stored on a physical server some where but the benefit of the cloud is you don't have to worry about the how and maintaining the hardware/software.

Some service lets you store and retrieve data, without any configuration ahead of time.

One of them is Parse.com. You may use API for store your data in a cloud https://parse.com/products/data#howitworks .

A Parse.com lets you manage your objects in the intuitive browser spreadsheet-like interface https://parse.com/products/data#overview .